# couldn't copy pdb file to another directory while consuming wcf web service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, visual-studio-2013

I have a WCF Web Service and there is one method which returns sensor lists. 
When I want to consume this web service in a Console Application in Debug Mode, I got these 2 errors as;

```
Could not copy "obj\Debug\ConsumeHelper.pdb" to "bin\Debug\ConsumeHelper.pdb". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.  ConsumeHelper
```

and

`Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\ConsumeHelper.pdb" to "bin\Debug\ConsumeHelper.pdb". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\ConsumeHelper.pdb' because it is being used by another process.  ConsumeHelper`

Also I'm adding consumer method as given below.

```
        SensorServiceClient client = 
                    new SensorServiceClient("WebHttpBinding_ISensorService");
        Sensor[] sensor = client.getAllSensors("true");  
        Console.WriteLine("Sensor name is "  + sensor[0].Name);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

So, can anyone lead to me solution? Thanks for everyone.

Comment: What is `ConsumeHelper` here? is it a separate project?

Comment: @Rahul yes it's my client project and it consumes WCF service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your latest comment where you say

> `ConsumeHelper` is client project and it consumes WCF service

Make sure you are not already running that project. I doubt it's already running and so the `pdb` file is not able to copy. Else, try running in `Release` mode instead of `Debug` mode.